# Redirect whole domain to a sub-folder on another domain in WP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have one domain that used to have its own WP installation, say `www.aaa.example`.

Now the content of this has been included in a different domain in a sub-page, say `bbb.example/aaa-subpage/`.

Also, the old domain `www.aaa.example` has a DNS `A` record pointing to the WP Server of `bbb.example`.

What I want now is, that all calls go to `www.aaa.example/*` should be redirected to `bbb.example/aaa-subpage/` no matter which sub-page on `aaa.example` was used. So everything should go to one sub-page in the new domain.

I have tried some 301 redirect plugins but so far no chance... all calls from `aaa.example` simply go to the top-level page of `bbb.example`.

Comment: A RewriteCond to check the request host name, followed by a RewriteRule that redirects _everything_ to BBB.

Comment: @CBroe That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Comment: Are both `aaa.example` and `bbb.example` served out of the same virtual host and directory?  Do they share a `.htaccess` file?

Comment: It’s the same provider and just two domains linked to the same WP Installation. So I guess only one htaccess in this case. 
The old installation was cancelled already and was with another provider.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect requests to `aaa.example/<anything>` to `bbb.example/aaa-subpage/` you would need to add the following mod_rewrite directives to the *top* of the root `.htaccess` file. Crucially, it must go *before* the WordPress front-controller (ie. before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker).

```
# Redirect "aaa.example/<anything>" to "bbb.example/aaa-subpage/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aaa\.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://bbb.example/aaa-subpage/ [R=301,L]
```

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive that should already appear later in the file (in the WordPress section).

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in the .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /aaa-subpage/
```

Comment: If the two domains are served from the same virtual host, that will redirect the home page of `aaa.example` and `bbb.example` to the subpage.  This would need an additional rewrite condition for the host name.